# Threads with Spring, wait, notify?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I haven't used any of Spring's threading support before.  Does it support any high level concept of the Thread class's wait and notify?

Comment: Can you give some details on what you want to achieve?

Comment: If it were comparable in concept to `wait` and `notify`, it wouldn't be very high level...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see [Task Executors and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). In addition there's [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) about the simplifications in 3.0, which uses the new Java 5 executor framework.

Answer (score 1):

The high-level threading - or rather concurrency - classes for Java are found in the `java.util.concurrent` package, included in the JRE since Java 5.

Take a look at the [package summary](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and see if it suits your needs.

I don't think that you need something extra which Spring can offer.

Comment: there is - integration of the task executors with the spring context - injecting dependencies in them, having them proxied by aop, etc. But for the basic support, you are right.